# Left bit shifting 255 (as a byte)

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

Can anyone explain why the following doesn't compile?

```
byte b = 255 << 1
```

The error:

> Constant value '510' cannot be converted to a 'byte'

I'm expecting the following in binary:

```
1111 1110
```

The type conversion has stumped me.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Numeric literals in C# are `int`, not `byte` (and the bit shift will be evaluated by the compiler, hence only the 510 remains). You are therefore trying to assign a value to a `byte` which does not fit. You can mask with 255:

```
byte b = (255 << 1) & 0xFF
```

to reduce the result to 8 bits again. Unlike Java, C# does not allow overflows to go by undetected. Basically you'd have two sensible options when trying to assign 510 to a byte: Either clamp at the maximum value, then you'd get 255, or throw away the bits that do not fit, in which case you'd get 254.

You can also use `unchecked`, as [lassevk mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737781/left-bit-shifting-255-as-a-byte/737810#737810):

```
byte b = unchecked((byte)(255 << 1));
```

Comment: Not sure why I thought 255 would be stored as a 8 bit

Comment: Well, 255 fits, everything above doesn't :)

Comment: It should be noted, as I was pushed here from another thread, that even if you have two bytes, any bitwise operation on them will return an int.

Comment: Silly question, why do you use a hex representation of 255 instead of just using 255?

Comment: @Sir: Habit when using numbers as bitmasks. If you're `and` -ing or `or` -ing with a number you don't care about its decimal representation; you want to see immediately what bits are set and which are not.

Answer (score 8):

You are shifting 255 by 1 bit, then trying to assign it to a byte.
`255 << 1 is 510`, and 510 won't fit in to a byte.

Answer (score 6):

The result of the `<<` operator is an `Int32`, not what you put into it.

You need to cast the result of the shift, not the input. Additionally, it will produce an overflow (it is larger than a byte afterall), so you need to specify that you need an unchecked cast.

In other words, this will work:

```
Byte b = unchecked((Byte)(255 << 1));
```

Answer (score 5):

```
byte b = 0xff & (255 << 1);
```

Answer (score 3):

have you tried casting it?

```
byte b = (byte)(255 << 1)
```

---

This is an interesting approach - the above code will work if wrapped in a `unchecked` block like this:

```
unchecked
{
    byte b = (byte)(255 << 1);
}
```

Since it is `unchecked` the value is truncated to the intended value of 254.  So it is possible to do this with a cast!

Comment: Maybe you mean (byte)(255 << 1) ?

Comment: try: byte b = (255 << 1) & 0xff;

Comment: casting is not the solution to everything ;)

Comment: I removed my (-1) as this will work if wrapped in "unchecked".

Answer (score 1):

```
255 << 1
```

will give you more than one byte.

Answer (score 0):

And since << has a higher precedence than & you can save the brackets:

```
byte b = 255 << 1 & 0xff;
```