# OR-ing bytes in C# gives int

Tags: c#, types, logic, bit-manipulation, byte

I have this code.

```
byte dup = 0;
Encoding.ASCII.GetString(new byte[] { (0x80 | dup) });
```

When I try to compile I get:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'int'
>   to 'byte'. An explicit conversion
>   exists (are you missing a cast?)

Why does this happen? Shouldn't | two bytes give a byte? Both of the following work, assuring that each item is a byte.

```
Encoding.ASCII.GetString(new byte[] { (dup) });
Encoding.ASCII.GetString(new byte[] { (0x80) });
```

Comment: This question answers it in more detail: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/737781/left-bit-shifting-255-as-a-byte . You have a string literal which is always cast to an int.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's that way by design in C#, and, in fact, dates back all the way to C/C++ - the latter also promotes operands to `int`, you just usually don't notice because `int -> char` conversion there is implicit, while it's not in C#. This doesn't just apply to `|` either, but to all arithmetic and bitwise operands - e.g. adding two `byte`s will give you an `int` as well. I'll quote the relevant part of the spec here:

> Binary numeric promotion occurs for
>   the operands of the predefined +, –,
>   *, /, %, &, |, ^, ==, !=, >, <, >=, and <= binary operators. Binary
>   numeric promotion implicitly converts
>   both operands to a common type which,
>   in case of the non-relational
>   operators, also becomes the result
>   type of the operation. Binary numeric
>   promotion consists of applying the
>   following rules, in the order they
>   appear here:
>
> - If either operand is of
>     type decimal, the other operand is
>     converted to type decimal, or a
>     compile-time error occurs if the other
>     operand is of type float or double.
> - Otherwise, if either operand is of
>     type double, the other operand is
>     converted to type double.
> - Otherwise,
>     if either operand is of type float,
>     the other operand is converted to type
>     float.
> - Otherwise, if either operand
>     is of type ulong, the other operand is
>     converted to type ulong, or a
>     compile-time error occurs if the other
>     operand is of type sbyte, short, int,
>     or long.
> - Otherwise, if either
>     operand is of type long, the other
>     operand is converted to type long.
> - Otherwise, if either operand is of
>     type uint and the other operand is of
>     type sbyte, short, or int, both
>     operands are converted to type long.
> - Otherwise, if either operand is of
>     type uint, the other operand is
>     converted to type uint.
> - Otherwise,
>     both operands are converted to type
>     int.

I don't know the exact rationale for this, but I can think about one. For arithmetic operators especially, it might be a bit surprising for people to get `(byte)200 + (byte)100` suddenly equal to `44`, even if it makes some sense when one carefully considers the types involved. On the other hand, `int` is generally considered a type that's "good enough" for arithmetic on most typical numbers, so by promoting both arguments to `int`, you get a kind of "just works" behavior for most common cases.

As to why this logic was also applied to bitwise operators - I imagine this is so mostly for consistency. It results in a single simple rule that is common for *all* non-boolean binary types.

But this is all mostly guessing. Eric Lippert would probably be the one to ask about the real motives behind this decision for C# at least (though it would be a bit boring if the answer is simply "it's how it's done in C/C++ and Java, and it's a good enough rule as it is, so we saw no reason to change it").

Comment: This is really interesting. This post deservses a lot of votes:)

Comment: sweet answer! good detail! Could've used a code snippet to demonstrate what would fix his problem, but all in all very interesting.

Comment: For completeness it would be worth mentioning that the `|=` etc operators do a cast implicitly.

Comment: Makes me wonder if this implicit cast comes at a processing cost though... the type of data I end up doing bitwise operations on are generally images (stuff like bitplane combining/splitting), so that's typically tens of thousands of bytes to process.

Answer (score 6):

The literal 0x80 has the type "int", so you are not oring bytes.

That you can pass it to the byte[] only works because 0x80 (as a literal) it is within the range of byte.

**Edit**: Even if 0x80 is cast to a byte, the code would still not compile, since oring bytes will still give int. To have it compile, the result of the or must be cast: `(byte)(0x80|dup)`

Comment: true, but still doesn't show how to fix it. simply casting 0x80 to byte still results in an error message because byte|byte => int.

Comment: Sorry, voted down. Doesn't explain the real problem at play here:  byte | byte = int32.

Comment: @blesh: no, that's not the real problem. 0x80 is of type int, not of type byte - contrary to what the OP claims (and apparently you also claim). So it's int|byte. Of course, if you were to fix it as (byte)0x80 | dup, it still wouldn't work because of the reason Lucas and you give.

Comment: The issue is a number in C# (a literal) is an integer. byte b = 42; is an integer not a byt

Comment: The asker was premature picking this as the solution because it didn't actually address the problem. The problem was he was getting an exception because (0x80 | dup) was returning an int... your solution to assure that you're casting both or'ed integrals by casting 0x80 as a byte will still throw the Exception. 

byte[] { ((byte)0x80 | dup) }; //throws the same exception.

This question needs moderated so someone doesn't come here looking for an answer and leave with the wrong one.

Comment: @blesh: you are mistaken claiming that Exceptions have to do anything with it. Instead, it's a compile time error, not a runtime error. In any case, I have added the discussion of byte|byte into the answer.

Answer (score 4):

```
byte dup = 0;
Encoding.ASCII.GetString(new byte[] { (byte)(0x80 | dup) });
```

The result of a bitwise Or (|) on two bytes is always an int.

Comment: As people pointed out 0x80 is an int literal. regardless, the issue at hand is int | byte returns an int, which can't be stuck in a byte[].