# Why is the resulting type of a division of short integers in Java not a short integer?

Tags: java, syntax

Consider this code:

```
public class ShortDivision {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        short i = 2;
        short j = 1;
        short k = i/j;
    }
}
```

Compiling this produces the error

```
ShortDivision.java:5: possible loss of precision
found   : int
required: short
        short k = i/j;
```

because the type of the expression i/j is apparently int, and hence must be cast to short.

Why is the type of `i/j` not short?

Comment: Because converting an int to a short would give possible loss of precision. (-32768 / -1)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

From the [Java spec](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/conversions.doc.html#170983):

> 5.6.2 Binary Numeric Promotion
>
> When an operator applies binary numeric promotion to a pair of operands, each of which must denote a value of a numeric type, the following rules apply, in order, using widening conversion (§5.1.2) to convert operands as necessary:
>
> If either operand is of type double, the other is converted to double.
>
> Otherwise, if either operand is of type float, the other is converted to float.
>
> Otherwise, if either operand is of type long, the other is converted to long.
>
> **Otherwise, both operands are converted to type int.**

For binary operations, small integer types are promoted to `int` and the result of the operation is `int`.

---

**EDIT:** Why is it like that? The short answer is that Java copied this behavior from C. A longer answer might have to do with the fact that all modern machines do at least 32-bit native computations, and it might actually be harder for some machines to do 8-bit and 16-bit operations.

See also: [OR-ing bytes in C# gives int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1214629/or-ing-bytes-in-c-gives-int/1214688#1214688)

Comment: further: Binary numeric promotion is performed on the operands of certain operators:

    - The multiplicative operators *, / and %

Comment: OK, I understand that the language specification says that the language should behave like this (otherwise the compiler wouldn't generate the error in the first place). But I don't understand the motivation behind it. Why are they promoting the types before doing the division rather than just dividing the shorts?

Comment: My bet is on "thats the way it is in C".  Java was designed to be attractive to C++ programmers - that requires things to be the same

Comment: Thanks for the link, that seemed like a reasonable enough explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the motivation: lets imagine the alternatives to this behaviour and see why they don't work:

**Alternative 1: the result should always be the same as the inputs.**

What should the result be for adding an int and a short?

What should the result be for multiplying two shorts? The result in general will fit into an int, but because we truncate to short, most multiplications will fail silently. Casting to an int afterwards won't help.

**Alternative 2: the result should always be the smallest type that can represent all possible outputs.**

If the return type were a short, the answer would not always be representable as a short.

A short can hold values -32,768 to 32,767. Then this result will cause overflow:

```
short result = -32768 / -1; // 32768: not a short
```

So your question becomes: why does adding two ints not return a long? What should multiplication of two ints be? A long? A BigNumber to cover the case of squaring integer min value?

**Alternative 3: Choose the thing most people probably want most of the time**

So the result should be:

- int for multiplying two shorts, or any int operations.
- short if adding or subtracting shorts, dividing a short by any integer type, multiplying two bytes, ...
- byte if bitshifting a byte to the right, int if bitshifting to the left.
- etc...

Remembering all the special cases would be difficult if there is no fundamental logic to them. It's simpler to just say: the result of integer operations is always an int.

Comment: What people want, isn't always the same as what is a good idea if you designed it again. A good example is the QWERTY keyboard arrangement.  Originally designed to *slow down* typists so that typewriters wouldn't jam up.  Still, I can't imagine using anything else as I'm used to it.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey: Yep. If Henry Ford had asked people what sort of car he should manufacture, many would have been asking for a cart with **6** horses instead of 4. Listening to what your users want is a good thing, but sometimes you need to give them something different from what they want because they're not even able to imagine a different solution than what they're used to.

Comment: For languages without operator overloading, why not have the result be the smaller of (largest possible result) or (size of receiving container)?  In most cases, such a rule would yield code which was as small or smaller than anything which could be expressed that would yield arithmetically-correct results using approach #1.  For example, if variables are 32 bits, `p=(x*y)/z;` would do a 32x32->64 multiply and a 64/32->32 divide.  If `p` and `z` were 16 bits, it would do a 32x32->64 multiply, a 64->32 overflow-checked reduction, and a 32/16->16 divide.

Answer (score 0):

It just a design choice to be consistent with C/C++ which were dominate languages when Java was designed.

For example, i * j could be implemented so the type is promoted from byte => short, short => int, and int => long, and this would avoid overflows but it doesn't. (It does in some languages) Casting could be used if the current behaviour was desired, but the loss of some bits would be clear.

Similarly i / j could be prompted from byte/short => float or int/long => double.