# Java - operations on native short always return int, why? and how?

Tags: java, boxing

I'm currently working with `short`, but every operations between shorts gives me `int`. I'm aware that Java doesn't provide short literals, so cast is required when declaring/assigning a new short variable.

But why standard operations (+ - / *) give an `int` as a result?
Is it because of Java auto-boxing mechanism?

Exemple (JDK 1.8):

```
private short prepareValue(short value)
{
    // here: no literal, so cast, but cast is not required for test?
    short sign = (value < 0) ? (short)-1 : (short)1;

    // here: short*short=int, so casting the result
    short absValue = (short)(value * sign);

    // here: the function returns a short, but same problem as before
    value = (short)(myFunctionOnlyOnPositive(absShort) * sign);

    // ... more things
    return value;
}
```

I took a look into [Conversions and Contexts](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7), but I didn't find any help on it. Even the documentation on [Short](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Short.html) isn't helping (I must be dumb or something else at this point). So can someone explain to me why does Java assume `short * short = int` ?

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2256864/why-is-the-resulting-type-of-a-division-of-short-integers-in-java-not-a-short-in

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2256864/why-is-the-resulting-type-of-a-division-of-short-integers-in-java-not-a-short-in

Comment: Thanks for the link @AndreasFester :-)