# Why is 7 / 3 not always an int? Why can it be assigned into byte or short while x/3 cannot?

Tags: java

I thought that the result of any arithmetic expression is at least an int. 7 / 3 is an expression - it has an operator (division).

But why does this compile fine?

```
byte b1 = 7 / 3;     // 7/3 is not a literal?
short b2 = 7 / 3;    // 7/3 is not a literal?
char b3 = 7 / 3;     // 7/3 is not a literal?
```

And f1() compile fine?

```
byte f1() {
    return 7 / 3;    // Why is it allowed?  Why isn't 7 / 3 an int ?
}

byte f2(int x) {
    return x / 3;   // c.ERR - type mismatch
}

byte f3(byte x) {
    return x / 3;   // c.ERR - type mismatch
}
```

P.S. The question is different, because I know that 7 / 3 would give 2 as a result of integer division (rounding towards zero), but it shall be an int, not byte or short.

Comment: It **is *always*** an `int`. See [JLS-5.1.3. Narrowing Primitive Conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3) for more.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2256864/why-is-the-resulting-type-of-a-division-of-short-integers-in-java-not-a-short-in, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895078/why-is-the-sum-of-bytes-integer, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21317631/java-char-int-conversions. (I'm having trouble finding an answer that properly explains assigning `7/3` to a `byte`, though. [My answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21317904/2891664) explains it for `char` which is essentially the same specification.)

Answer (score 11):

```
byte f1() {
    return 7 / 3;    // Why is it allowed?  Why isn't 7 / 3 an int ?
}
```

In the above snippet, the result is within byte range (`-128` to `127`), and the compiler is smart enough to realize that it can implicitly cast the `int` result to a `byte` to be returned by your method.

> [JLS 14.17](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.17): When a `return` statement with an *Expression* appears in a method declaration, the ***Expression* must be assignable ([§5.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2)) to the declared return type** of the method, or a compile-time error occurs.
>
> [JLS 5.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2): If the expression is a **constant expression** ([§15.28](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28)) of type `byte`, `short`, `char`, or `int`:
>
> - A narrowing primitive conversion may be used if the variable is of type `byte`, `short`, or `char`, and the value of the constant expression is representable in the type of the variable.

---

```
byte f2(int x) {
    return x / 3;   // c.ERR - type mismatch
}
```

In the above snippet, because `x` is an `int`, it can be a large number that, when divided by `3`, will **not** be within `byte` range, so the compiler knows that it shouldn't attempt to implicitly cast it to a `byte`, as that result may not be desired.

> [JLS 14.17](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.17): When a `return` statement with an *Expression* appears in a method declaration, the *Expression* must be assignable ([§5.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2)) to the declared return type of the method, or **a compile-time error occurs**.

---

```
byte f3(byte x) {
    return x / 3;   // c.ERR - type mismatch
}
```

In the above snippet, when doing arithmetic with a `byte` and an `int`, the `byte` will be automatically upcasted to an `int` (as defined in the JLS).  This results in the same scenario as number two; even though we know that the result must be within `byte` range, the compiler doesn't, because dividing by `3` could be changed to being multiplied by `9999...`.

> [JLS 15.17](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17): Binary numeric promotion is performed on the operands ([§5.6.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2)).
>
> [JLS 5.6.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2): Widening primitive conversion ([§5.1.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2)) is applied to convert either or both operands as specified by the following rules:
>
> - If either operand is of type `double`, the other is converted to `double`.
> - Otherwise, if either operand is of type `float`, the other is converted to `float`.
> - Otherwise, if either operand is of type `long`, the other is converted to `long`.
> - Otherwise, **both operands are converted to type `int`**.

Comment: Makes sense....

Comment: Added JLS quotes. Hope that is ok.

Comment: @Andreas Absolutely, it looks great.  Thanks :)