# Unsigned left shift in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, bit-shift

This should be an easy one for folks, but how do I pull off an unsigned left shift in [VB.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_.NET) while using `Option Strict`?

Maybe I am doing it wrong, but while trying to implement my own IP2Long function (I have my reasons), I'm testing things to make sure I have my head wrapped around the conversion process properly. I tried a few tests, and all seem to cause errors.

```
Dim a As Int32
a = CUint(172 << 24) 'Constant expression not representable in type 'UInteger'
a = DirectCast((172 << 24), UInt32) 'Value of type 'Integer' cannot be converted to 'UInteger'
a = Convert.ToUInt32(172 << 24) 'Compiles, but throws an OverflowException
```

The last one is especially befuddling. `172 << 24` is a mere 2,885,681,152, well under the limit imposed by the UInt32 data type. My assumption is .NET is doing the left-shift in signed mode, then tries to convert, to unsigned, and this tosses up some kind of error.

Basically, my question boils down to this: why do unsigned numerics have to act like such hacks to the .NET framework at times? Is it really that hard for Microsoft to make unsigned data types intrinsic to the framework?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The last one is especially befuddling.
>   172 << 24 is a mere 2,885,681,152,
>   well under the limit imposed by the
>   UInt32 data type. My assumption is
>   .NET is doing the left-shift in signed
>   mode, then tries to convert, to
>   unsigned, and this tosses up some kind
>   of error.

This error is not wrong. 172 takes up 8 bits. You shift it 24 bits and the 8th bit is now the 32nd bit. This is a reserved sign bit. Therefore it is technically overflowing.

---

### Treat integers like C#

**VB.NET** will check for an integer overflow unlike in **C#**.

To get **VB.NET** to ignore **OveflowExceptions Exceptions** goto:

```
Project properties->Compile->Advanced Compiler Option->"Remove integer overflow checks"
```

Or [compile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/key2x70f%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) with

```
vbc foo.vb /removeintchecks
```

---

### Explicit state bit operations

If you are determined to leave overflow checks in your code, you have to explicitly tell it you are using bit operations using the [BitConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.aspx) Class:

```
''//This will work
a = BitConverter.ToInt32(BitConverter.GetBytes(172 << 24), 0)
```

---

### Visual Basic literals

Also keep in mind you can add [literals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9cz43ek%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) to your code in VB.NET and explicitly state constants as unsigned.

Comment: Ah, you removed the bit about literals.  That was actually a good answer.  I thought literals were a GCC-specific thing, but I guess that's one of those little footnotes in VB.Net that's easily overlooked.  Not too interested in disabling overflow checks, however.  That doesn't work around the actual problem, just sweeps it under the rug.

Comment: @Kumba: I think it has to do more with the history of each language. C# is based upon C-like syntax where integers overflowed. Visual Basic is an introductory language and it might confuse new programmers if their integers went from 2,147,483,647 to -2,147,483,648.

Comment: @snmcdonald: Agreed about the language differences.  But this seems to extend into the framework itself.  I've read that UInt32 is a structure of some type (I haven't investigated yet), rather than an intrinsic data type built into the CLR itself, and that unsigned values really aren't native to VB.NET (and C#).  I suppose C# makes it easier (to an extent), since casting is `(datatype)Foo`, whereas in VB, you've got the ugly syntax of `DirectCast(Foo, datatype)`.

Comment: @Kumba: I am not a CLR guru, but as I understand it, UInts, Ints, etc... are not primitives are you would think of as Java, they are indeed structs. However, do not think of them as a C++ struct (a class default to public). A structure in the .NET framework is a stack based object. This allows you to think of them as a primitive as in Java or C++, however, as a stack based object you can add methods.

Comment: @snmcdonald: Yes, I'm aware that Structures are valuetypes in .NET (while Classes are reference), and this governs where they're allocated.  I'm not from a Java background, or even C++.  I think of "primitives" in a C-syntax, where 'Int32' is an 8-bit number whose last bit is used for the sign and 'UInt32' is an 8-bit number that has access to all of its bits.  Never got into compilers or even assembler, but I would figure that .NET could easily handle this tiny little difference instead of having to kludge things as it apparently does for unsigned numerics.

Comment: @snmcdonald: That said, I misjudged VB.NET's intelligence.  It was complaining per my original post because I was simply testing a constant expression.  As soon as I stuck said expression into a `UInt32` variable and then did a shift on it, it works fine (this struct for unsigned ints probably overrides the shift ops to properly handle them).  Otherwise, VB falls back to its default numeric format, that being a signed integer (unless explicitly overridden, per your suggestion of literals).

Comment: @Kumba: Even C# forces some explicit casting with the unchecked syntax: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/737781/left-bit-shifting-255-as-a-byte. Although, I do not see that as a negative, I think it forces the programmer to be aware and enforces stronger typing discipline. Don't get me wrong I love C but it is considered a weakly typed language.

Comment: @snmcdonald: Also, seems when I break apart my IPv4 address, I have to store it into an array of UInt32's if I want things to work properly.  Storing those into a byte array doesn't work, because byte's idea of shifting is different than a UInt32's.  Ah, curiouser and curiouser things get the deeper into the rabbit hole we go...

Comment: @Kumba: A bytes definition of shifting a byte should not be different than an unsigned int. If you need a signed byte consider SByte. Both a byte and unsigned byte will shift and drop the carry bit. If you need a string of bits consider a Bit Array http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3684002/bitarray-shift-bits

Comment: I think it's safer to say that C is vaguely-typed....GCC can throw some of the most cryptic of errors at you sometimes, and it ultimately boils down to sticking an implicit cast in the right spot.  That said, I'm a big proponent of strongly-typing.  VB.NET is really my first exposure to a true OOP language, so that lack of a Java background has its detriments.  Working with PHP doesn't help, either, because of its type inference.  Hence, unlearning some things and re-learning other things.  The link to the C# question is also a good pointer!

Comment: @snmcdonald: Per the byte shift, I wasn't clear enough (these comment fields are really lacking at times on this site).  What I meant was `172L << 24` is going to have a different answer than `172S << 24` (and ditto for 172 as a byte).  Pause and think, and it makes perfect sense why this is so.  But at a first glance, it isn't an immediate understanding.

Comment: @Kumba: If you are coming from a C background I really think a C# background would be better suited for you.

Comment: @snmcdonald: I've felt that way at times.  It's easier to find C# answers on this site and via Google, too.  But I'm far too deep into my project to go and convert all the code to C# now.