# Combine two bytes to short using left-shift

Tags: c#, casting, bit-shift

I have a high byte and a low byte I would like to convert to short.

I have implemented this, which seems to work, however I am a bit confused on why. Both `high_byte` and `low_byte` are cast as `byte`s.

```
short word = (short)(high_byte << 8 | low_byte);
```

In this code, should the `high_byte << 8` be zero? Then I tried this:

```
(byte)1 << 8
```

which equals `256`, which I thought should be `0`. I guess I am clearly missing something.

Could someone please explain?

Comment: Instead of (byte)1 << 8, you probably want (byte)(1 << 8)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From the [C# language specification](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7029), section 4.1.5:

> The integral-type unary and binary operators always operate with signed 32-bit precision, unsigned 32-bit precision, signed 64-bit precision, or unsigned 64-bit precision:
>
> ...
>
> For the binary `<<` and `>>` operators, the left operand is converted to type `T`, where `T` is the first of `int`, `uint`, `long`, and `ulong` that can fully represent all possible values of the operand. The operation is then performed using the precision of type `T`, and the type of the result is `T`.

That is, whenever you apply any operators to integral types in C#, the result is always a minimum of 32-bits. There are other rules (given in the `...`) for other operators, which define exactly how the final types are determined.

---

(As an aside, I'd have thought that this was important enough to mention in the [C# Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/618ayhy6.aspx) but I'm blowed if I can find it in there anywhere)

Answer (score 4):

Why do you expect the last piece of code to be equal to 0? You can check the type in Immediate Window.

```
(1 << 8).GetType()
```

It returns `System.Int32`.

Answer (score 4):

The result of `<<` is minimally an int, so no, `someByte << 8` doesn't yield `0`, as the result fits in an int.

If you want `(byte)1 << 8` to clamp the result to a byte, use `(byte)((1 << 8) & 255)`. This will always result in `0`, so why you'd want that...

See also [Left bit shifting 255 (as a byte)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737781/left-bit-shifting-255-as-a-byte).

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this:

```
byte[] Bytes = new byte[2] { byte1, byte2 };
Convert.ToUInt16(Bytes);
```

Comment: He's not asking how to do this; he has code that works. He's asking why it works.